# Popup when clicking a disabled button in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I want a popup if user clicks on disabled button.
I have disabled the button using 'disabled' function of shinyjs package.

Comment: I suggest you to check carefully the SO help center, because your question is too generic. What kind of code have you performed since now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `observeEvent` to make a modal dialog, that responds on your button. If you want it to only happen when it is disabled, you could use an `if`-statement to check for the button status.

Another way to do it is through HTML and Javascript, using `alert()`, and tie that to the class of disabled buttons.

UI

```
actionButton("show", "Show modal dialog")
```

Server

```
observeEvent(input$show, {
      showModal(modalDialog(
        title = "Somewhat important message",
        "This is a somewhat important message.",
        easyClose = TRUE,
        footer = NULL
      ))
```

[Take a look at the documentation.](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/modalDialog.html)